# D7 Organic Groups - Set group context in panel

Tags: views, organic-groups, panels, 7

I'm using Organic Groups for committee membership on a university intranet. Each group has a landing page [created with panels per these d.o instructions](http://drupal.org/node/1041198). This is working fine, however, I cannot get the panel to pass the group context (gid / group ID) to views contained within the panel. In D6, Group ID (gid) and Node ID (nid) were the same; in D7 they are different. I need to pass the group ID to a view in order to show content generated by that group on the landing page. I've been struggling with this for a while. Am I missing something really basic?

Versions:

- **Context** 7.x-3.0-beta2
- **Context OG** 7.x-1.x-dev
- **Organic Groups** 7.x-1.4
- **Panels** 7.x-3.2
- **Views** 7.x-3.3

Thanks,

Jordan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh. After a week of fighting with this, I figured out that the "OG Members" Content Pane will work after some extensive customization. Somehow, I deleted this in my install, so I didn't know about it. I will use this as a starting point template for future group/panel needs.

Comment: did you find one ?

Comment: In my opinion this is not an answer since the customizations weren't even stated. This is probably a similar issue to my question: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/89718/context-og-reaction-block-does-not-appear-on-views-override-pages