# Context OG Reaction: Block does not appear on Views override pages

Tags: views, organic-groups, 7

I'm using the module [Context OG](https://drupal.org/project/context_og) in order to use the condition "OG - Member Role" in a context.

The context by itself works without problems, until I override the node page with a view. The view by itself works as well, and conditions trigger with every other non-Context OG Reaction. Just not with the Context OG provided reactions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Just a quick idea: would it work if you load and display the view programmatically in `node.tpl.php` file? That way you won't be overriding the node page, context should work and you will get your view to replace the content of the node.